# How to pass variables between html in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use `$rootScope` to pass a boolean between two files and works perfectly... ONCE. Then, it does not change even tho the `CLICKED` log appears.

What the hell??

navbar.html

```
ng-click="openRightSideMenu(); // Works well
```

navbar.js

```
$scope.openRightSideMenu = () => {
     console.log("CLICKED") // this always logs, so ng-click is working well
     $rootScope.rightSideMenuOpen = true; // Opens the sideMenu but ONLY WORKS ONCE!! It's not change to true the second time
}
```

sideMenu.html

```
ng-class="rightSideMenuOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'" // Toogle between open
            // and closed, works well but I cannot open the second time

ng-click="rightSideMenuOpen = false" // Close works well
```

Any idea why `$rootScope.rightSideMenuOpen` only works once and doesn't change the second time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a data hiding problem.

The `ng-click` is setting the `rightSideMenuOpen` property of the local $scope of the element. This hides the value of that property on $rootScope.

```
ng-class="rightSideMenuOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'" // Toogle between open
            // and closed, works well but I cannot open the second time

̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶r̶i̶g̶h̶t̶S̶i̶d̶e̶M̶e̶n̶u̶O̶p̶e̶n̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶"̶
ng-click="$root.rightSideMenuOpen = false"
```

This way the `ng-click` changes the property on $rootScope.